# ol3 / OpenLayers 3: How to use readNetworkLinks method for ol.format.KML()?

Tags: kml, openlayers-3

I am looking for some guidance on how to implement the readNetworkLinks method of ol.format.KML() in OL3.

```
var kmlURL = 'kml/NLExample/TestLinkNL.kml'
var kmlFormat = new ol.format.KML()

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   url: kmlURL,
   format: kmlFormat
  });
```

I use the above code to create a KML layer with no problems, but I need to also display other KML that are referenced via network links in the top-level KML.  I'm not quite sure the syntax for using the readNetworkLinks() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readNetworkLinks](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.KML.html#readNetworkLinks) takes a KML document as String, so you would have to load your file manually and then parse the network links:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var url = 'kml/NLExample/TestLinkNL.kml';
$.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
  var kmlFormat = new ol.format.KML();
  var features = kmlFormat.readFeatures(response);
  source.addFeatures(features);

  // read the network links
  var links = kmlFormat.readNetworkLinks(response);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: What would be the correct way to deal with the returned links? Perform new ajax calls?

Comment: I found the github issue related to this question. [ol-3171](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3171). 
Apparently the should make its own requests for each of the `NetworkLinks`.